# Получения даты изменения файла из массива Java

Tags: java, массивы, map

Изначальная задача - получить весь список классов в порядка даты последнего изменения(миллисекунды с 1970). Половина задачи уже решена, но вот тут возникла проблема.

Список классов мы уже получили, отсортируем их позже через TreeMap, а если даты модификации будут одинаковые - отсортируем по алфавиту через компаратор. Разберемся с этим позже, сейчас следующая задача

```
    public static List<Class> find(String pkgname, String beginStr) {
    List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();
    ArrayList<Long> Dates = new ArrayList<Long>();

    File directory = null;
    String relPath = pkgname.replace('.', '/');

    URL resource = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(relPath);





    if (directory != null && directory.exists()) {
        // Получаем список всех файлов в папке
        String[] files = directory.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            // Берем только файлы с расширением .class
            if (files[i].endsWith(".class")) {

                // Убираем расширение
                new Date(files[i].lastModified())
```

//Вставляем запрос на дату изменения файла. lastModified подчеркивает красным.

```
                String className = files[i].substring(0, files[i].length() - 6);

                if (className.toLowerCase().substring(0, beginStr.length()).equals(beginStr.toLowerCase())) {
                    String fullClassName = pkgname + '.' + className;


                }
            }
        }
    }

    return classes;
}}
```

Чувствую, туплю по черному где то. 
Может некуда ему информацию помещать? 
Идеально конечно было бы сразу загнать без двух промежуточных ArrayList информацию сразу в TreeMap Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу подчеркивания красным:
Вы ведь делаете вызов метода lastModified() у String. Вы ведь бежите в цикле по массиву String[], а там не файлы, а строки. Файл еще на основе этой строки надо получить, и только потом можно будет у него вызвать lastModified()

По поводу создания TreeMap

- До уже готового Вашего цикла создайте пустую TreeMap
- Внутри цикла, воспользовавшись именем файла создайте объект File.
- Положите в мапу.

Пример рабочего кода

```
package ru.yaklimenko;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    static final String CLASS_FILE_EXTENSION = ".class";

    /**
     * сортировка по дате последних изменений
     */
    static final Comparator<File> MODIFIED_DATE_FILE_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
            if (o1.lastModified() < o2.lastModified()) {
                return -1;
            } else if (o1.lastModified() == o2.lastModified()) {
                return o1.getAbsolutePath().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            return 1;
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeMap<File, Class> classesByFiles = find("ru.yaklimenko", ""); // получил мапу
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<>(classesByFiles.keySet()); //получил список файлов из мапы
        Collections.sort(files, MODIFIED_DATE_FILE_COMPARATOR);// посортировал

        // теперь можно бежать по отсортированному циклу и брать классы сначала от старых файлов двигаясь к более молодым
        for (File file : files) {
            Class cls = classesByFiles.get(file);
            //do something
        }
    }


    /**
     * метод соберет и разложит по мапе классы из заданного package     
     */
    public static TreeMap<File, Class> find(String pkgname, String beginStr) {
        List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();
        ArrayList<Long> Dates = new ArrayList<Long>();


        String relPath = pkgname.replace('.', '/');

        URL resource = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(relPath);
        assert resource != null;
        File directory = new File(resource.getPath());

        if (directory != null && directory.exists()) {
            // Получаем список всех файлов в папке
            String[] files = directory.list();
            TreeMap<File, Class> resMap = new TreeMap<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                // Берем только файлы с расширением .class
                if (!files[i].endsWith(CLASS_FILE_EXTENSION)) {
                    continue;
                }
                File file = new File(files[i]);
                // Убираем расширение
                //new Date(files[i].lastModified())

                String className = files[i].substring(0, files[i].lastIndexOf('.'));

                try {
                    resMap.put(file, Class.forName(pkgname + "." + className));
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //я не понял, зачем эти 3 строки ниже из оригинального кода
                if (className.toLowerCase().substring(0, beginStr.length()).equals(beginStr.toLowerCase())) {
                    String fullClassName = pkgname + '.' + className;
                }

            }
            return resMap;
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш пример просто дорабатывает до строчки ' else if (o1.lastModified() == o2.lastModified()) {
                System.out.println(2929);
                return o1.getAbsolutePath().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getAbsolutePath());'  и завершает программу. Т.е. он по видимому считает что даты модификации файлов одинаковы. Я работаю в IntellijIdea, может там при запуске проекта все классы в проекте обновляются до текущего значения?

Comment: Надо поотлаживаться и посмотреть на значения дат. Так или иначе, если ответ Вам помог, поставьте, пожалуйста, напротив ответа галочку.